# servlet or ejb singleton to initialize web app

Tags: servlets, web, initialization, ejb

I need to initialize state of web application.
I can use initialization servlet with load-on-startup = 0.
Or I can use singleton ejb service.

What is better to use and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special "thing" for initialization of web app - ServletContextListener.
it is used like this:

```
package example;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ServletContextExample implements ServletContextListener{
    ServletContext context;
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
       ... some init work
}
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
        ... some destroy work
}
```

}

And in web.xml

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    example.ServletContextExample
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think **load-on-startup** is better than **ejb**.
i have used load on start up in my web application.

```
 <servlet>
   <servlet-class>com.agileinfotech.bsviewer.servlet.InitServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InitServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/InitServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```